# Electrum: seed is 0 length . Lost seed

Tags: electrum, seed

Its been months since Ive used my electrum wallet.

When I try and send coin I get an invalid password message.

Then when I go to my seed, I type in that same password and it takes me to the seed generator and says my seed is 0 length.

I see there was someone else with this same issue, he was just two characters off. If thats the case, I kind of know my password. What kind of brute force programs could I use to crack my password?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because you entered a wrong password. There was an old version of Electrum that sometimes returned a zero length seed instead of raising an Incorrect Password error.

Before posting issues, upgrade your software.